# Remove characters from string builder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm trying to run a loop to remove some  characters from a string. but when I'm running the following code I get output(I on) only from the first run. I don't get the rest of the string. Can someone please help what I need to add here ? only shows the result from the first iteration. Thanks

```
someStr = "I don't know this";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(someStr);
int n = 3
for (int i = n - 1; i < sb.length(); i = n + 1) {
    sb = sb.deleteCharAt(i);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: What is `n`?...

Comment: Check what your increment statement is actually doing

Comment: n can be any integer like 2,3,4 etc

Comment: It's 3 in my example.

Comment: @user3396478 I suggest you use a debugger and trace what the for loop is doing each time the loop executes. I think the reason you're not getting the rest of the string will become painfully apparent when you do that.

Comment: Then at each loop i is equal to n+1 so 4 and doesn't increment.

Comment: if you edit your post to include input and your expected output, it would help us with explaining what your fault in logic is

Comment: "n can be any integer" is not useful for anyone, it doesn't clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The third part of the for statement is the instruction that should increment or decrement your index.

There, it is always 4.

To be clearer :

```
1st iteration : i = 2 => you remove the 'd', your string is now "I on't know this"

2nd iteration : i = 4 => you remove the ''', your string is now "I ont know this"

3rd iteration : i = 4 => you remove the 't', your string is now "I on know this"

4th iteration : i = 4 => you remove the ' ', your string is now "I onknow this"
```

...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove characters from a String I recommend you to use Regex. This is an example to replace with empty strings the characters that you need to remove:

```
public static String cleanWhitPattern(String sample, String , String regex) {

    if (sample != null && regex != null) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.replaceAll("");
        }

        return sample;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now, you simply call this method with your required pattern:

```
System.out.print(cleanWithPattern("I don't know this", "o*"));
```

And your output should be this:

`I dn't knw this`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use String.replaceAll()?

```
someStr = "I don't know this";
System.out.print("Output :" );
System.out.println(someStr .replaceAll("t", ""));
```

Comment: Can you please understand the question? It is on StringBuilder class not on String class.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to remove the char "k" from your string then you can do the following

JAVA:

```
String someStr = "I don't know this";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(someStr);

if(sb.toString().contains("k")){
  int index = sb.indexOf("k");
  sb.deleteCharAt(index);
  System.out.println(sb.toString());
}else{
  System.out.println("No such a char");
}
```

KOTLIN:

```
val someStr: String = "I don't know this"
val sb: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(someStr)

if(sb.toString().contains("k")){
  val index: Int = sb.indexOf("k")
  sb.deleteCharAt(index)
  print(sb.toString())

  }else{
   print("No such a char")
}
```

Of course, you can do many combinations or many improvements depends of your desired output.